# Is there a way I can dynamically pivot and assign values?

Tags: sql-server, window-functions

I have a table **candidates**

```
id          candidate_name
---------------------------
1            john
2            mary
```

a table **units**

```
name
--------
unit1
unit2
unit3
```

and a table **achieved**

```
id cand_id unit
----------------
1  1       unit3
2  2       unit1
3  2       unit2
```

i would like to generate an output as

```
id  candidate_name  unit1  unit2  unit3
---------------------------------------
1       john        null   null   Y
2       mary        Y      Y      null
```

Any way I can achieve this?

DDL

```
create table candidates (id int, name varchar(20))
create table units (name varchar(20))
create table achieved(id int, cand_id int, unit varchar(20))

insert into candidates values(1,'john'),(2,'mary')
insert into units values('unit1'),('unit2'),('unit3')
insert into achieved values(1,1,'unit3'),(2,2,'unit1'),(3,2,'unit2')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes but you have to use dynamic SQL for it.

```
DECLARE @ListToPivot NVARCHAR(255);
SELECT @ListToPivot = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(u.unit), ',')
FROM   dbo.units AS u;

DECLARE @SqlStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SqlStatement = N'
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT
             c.id,
             c.candidate_name,
             a.unit,
             ''Y'' as unitachieved
        FROM dbo.achived AS a
             JOIN dbo.candidates AS c ON c.id = a.cand_id
    ) SourceTable
    PIVOT (
      MAX(unitachieved)
      FOR unit
      IN (
        ' + @ListToPivot + N'
      )
    ) AS PivotTable
  ';
--PRINT @SqlStatement;
EXEC (@SqlStatement);
```

Next time, please add scripts to generate the data.